# Java web application calling a SOAP service on weblogic is unstable in production

Tags: java, soap, weblogic

I have a Java web application deployed on an Oracle WebLogic 11g server. The application makes calls to a SOAP service also written in java and deployed on the same WebLogic 11g server. The SOAP service has two method which are called one after the other. The Body of the two calls are very similar, with the only difference being that the second one has two extra parameters, one of them being a base64 encoded signature image.

We have the same setup on our Production server and our Test server.

The application works 100% of the time on the test server. On the production server the call to the first method of the SOAP service executes correctly all of the time but the call to the second method only works sometimes. From what we can see so far is that when the method does not work then the method is not being called at all.

Is there anything that might cause this instability that we have missed?

**UPDATE**

I was incorrect in saying `We have the same setup on our Production server and our Test server.`

The production environment is actually distributed over two servers. If we hard code the calls to the SOAP service to only access one of the nodes then the application works perfectly.

It seems as though we have set up the load balancing or available hosts incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that an exception is preventing from reaching the 2nd method call or some configuration properties are not set on the production server...

Try running your application with Production profile and investigate further.